# Positional argument passing

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a method

```
public function show (text:Object="", title:String="", body=String=""){
    //blah
}
```

I want text to get the default value, and pass in values for the other two parameters. I was wondering if there is some way I can call it as such

```
show(title="sample", body="xyz");
```

Sorry if this question is really basic, I just started picking up Actionscript, and my limited googling skills didn't return any fruitful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrast to the other answers, you could do this:

```
public function show(params:Object):void
{
    var text:String = params.text || "";
    var title:String = params.title || "";
    var body:String = params.body || "";

   // blah
}
```

And then:

```
show({ title: "sample", body: "xyz" });
```

I of course advise against this for reasons related to code readability and maintainability, but it's still useful info.

If you do decide to use this approach, be sure to document your methods *clearly*, e.g.

```
// Relevant keys for params:
// text:String, title:String, body:String
// ...describe each here
public function show(params:Object):void
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to do this; other than to manually send in the default value:

```
show ("", "sample", "xyz");
```

And that kind of defeats the purpose of having a default in the first place.  Generally, I'll try to organize my method signatures by putting required items first; items with defaults that are likely to be changed next; and finally items with defaults that are unlikely to change.

This is not always a trivial decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in action script

```
show(title="sample", body="xyz");
```

If we were in C++ land you could have overloaded show and have 2 methods with different signatures, but you can't do that either. What I usually do is make 2 methods with different params and call the base function :

```
public function showTextTitleBody(text:Object="",title:String="",body:String="")
{
   //do your thing with the 3 params
}

public function showTitleBody(title:String="",body:String="")
{
   showTextTitleBody("",title,body);
}
```